# Which File Is Missing? "i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: No such file or directory"

Tags: macos, g++

I'm getting the following error from my compiler:

```
g++ -c -m32 tracecone.cpp -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/X11/include/GL -I/Users/owner/Documents/raytrace/Graphics -I../RayTrace -I/Users/owner/Documents/raytrace/Graphics -I/Users/owner/Documents/raytrace/VrMath -I/Users/owner/Documents/raytrace/OpenglRender -I/Users/owner/Documents/raytrace/RaytraceMgr 
g++ -o -m32 tracecone  ../RayTrace/RayTraceData.o tracecone.o  /Users/owner/Documents/raytrace/OpenglRender/GlutRenderer.o /Users/owner/Documents/raytrace/RaytraceMgr/SceneDescription.o  -L/usr/X11/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/Users/owner/Documents/raytrace/Graphics -L/Users/owner/Documents/raytrace/VrMath -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lX11 -lXext -lXmu -lXext -lXmu -lXt -lXi -lSM -lICE -lraygraph -lvrmath
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: tracecone: No such file or directory
make: *** [tracecone] Error 1
```

However, I am not sure which file it's saying is not there. Does it mean `tracecone`? or one of the library files? Either way, it looks like everything is right where it should be.

What could cause this error?

Here is my make file:

```
PROG    = tracecone
RBASE= /Users/owner/Documents/raytrace
GDIR=$(RBASE)/Graphics
MDIR=$(RBASE)/VrMath
ODIR=$(RBASE)/OpenglRender
MANDIR=$(RBASE)/RaytraceMgr

CFLAGS  = -w -s -O2 -ansi -DSHM 
XLIBS   = -lX11 -lXext -lXmu -lXext -lXmu -lXt -lXi -lSM -lICE
LIBS    = -lglut -lGLU -lGL
RAYLIBS = -lraygraph -lvrmath
INCLS   = -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/X11/include/GL
INCL1   = -I$(GDIR) -I../RayTrace -I$(GDIR) -I$(MDIR) -I$(ODIR) -I$(MANDIR) 
LIBDIR  = -L/usr/X11/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L$(GDIR) -L$(MDIR)
#source codes
SRCS = $(PROG).cpp 

#substitute .cpp by .o to obtain object filenames
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
#in ../Graphics
OBJOD = $(ODIR)/GlutRenderer.o
OBJO = GlutRenderer.o
OBJMAND = $(MANDIR)/SceneDescription.o
OBJMAN = SceneDescription.o
OBJ_temp = ../RayTrace/RayTraceData.o

#$< evaluates to the target's dependencies, 
#$@ evaluates to the target

$(PROG): $(OBJS)  
    g++ -o -m32 $@  $(OBJ_temp) $(OBJS)  $(OBJOD) $(OBJMAND)  $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) $(XLIBS) $(RAYLIBS)

$(OBJS): 
    g++ -c -m32 $*.cpp $(INCLS) $(INCL1)

$(OBJ1):
    cd $(GDIR); g++ -m32 -c $*.cpp $(INCLS)

$(OBJM):
    cd $(MDIR); g++ -m32 -c $*.cpp $(INCLS)

$(OBJO):
    cd $(ODIR); g++ -m32 -c $*.cpp $(INCLS)

$(OBJMAN):
    cd $(MANDIR); g++ -m32 -c $*.cpp $(INCLS)
clean:
    rm $(OBJS) 

clean1:
    rm $(OBJD1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place your target right after -o flag:
`g++ -o $@ -m32 ...`

Flag -o means output and in case of `g++ -o tracecone ...` you'll specify `tracecone` as output, but in case `g++ -o -m32 tracecone ...` you are specifying `-m32` as output and `tracecone` as one of the object files. And g++ says that there is no such object file because there is actually no such file.

Comment: I did this and ended up with an error like this `ld: warning: ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/owner/Documents/raytrace/OpenglRender/GlutRenderer.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7f 0x45 0x4c 0x46 0x 2 0x 1 0x 1 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386):`, I have no idea what that means. Perhaps I should start another question.

Comment: I'll answer in that question. You can close this one.